# jQuery ajax() returns object with error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        success: function () {
            $("#foo").text("second success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $("#foo").text(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    });
    });
```

This is the markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
</body>
```

The data that is returned (serialized and placed into `#foo`) is:

```
{
"readyState":0,
"responseText":"",
"status":0,
"statusText":"error"
}
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/U2gm9/4/

Comment: I just went to that URL and got no errors. Is flickr.com blocked where you are? What happens if you enter that URL into a web browser?

Comment: Please read the documentation carefully. The `error` callback does **not** receive a single `data` argument.

Comment: @Phil--I know that, I put it in just for convenience's sake. On a real call I would add the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `dataType: 'jsonp'`

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success: function () {
            $("#foo").text("second success");
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#foo").text("error");
        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tZLBB/)

Using [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getjson/)

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?').done(function (data) {
        $("#foo").text("second success");
        console.log(data)
    }).fail(function () {
        $("#foo").text("error");
    }).always(function () {})
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N7s8P/)

Comment: what do I do if the server I am sending the request to does not support JSONP?

Comment: @codeninja since you are making a cross domain ajax request the target resource has to support jsonp or if you want to support only modern browsers then you can look at [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: It doesn't seem like CORS requires me to add anything to my ajax call... or am I missing something? The example in the link you sent resembles what I have above.